# Sending List<Object> WCF POST

Tags: c#, wcf

Can anyone show me how to send a List as input parameters in WCF POST method ?

i have a class like this:

```
    public class CreateBudget
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string pr_code { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public List<BudgetTransactionRequest> transactions { get; set; } 

    }
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://mlpt-web.com/CRM/services")]
        public class BudgetTransactionRequest
        {
            [DataMember]
            public string transaction_code { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public double? amount { get; set; }
        }
```

and `[OperationContract]` like this:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
         ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,

         UriTemplate = "/CreateBudget"
         )]
        void CreateTransactions(CreateBudget cbreq);
```

I tried to test call using fiddler with this following string:

```
    {
"CreateBudget":{"pr_code": "AFK"},
"Transactions":[{"transaction_code":"PRS-0001", "amount": 2000.000},{"transaction_code":"PRS-0002", "amount": 3000.000} ]
}
```

I get http 400 error (bad request error). Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it.

```
{
 "pr_code": "AFK",
"Transactions":[{"transaction_code":"PRS-0001", "amount": 2000.000},{"transaction_code":"PRS-0002", "amount": 3000.000} ]
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: I found that the problem is in the server code. I Recieve error message: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index.